# Wrapping a generic type into an object allows for unsafe assignments

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I’m confused by the code below. I have a type such that `Type<boolean>` is not assignable to `Type<true>`, but if I wrap it into an object type (`BoxType` below), then suddenly `BoxType<boolean>` becomes (wrongly) assignable to `BoxType<true>`. What is happening and how can I prevent it?

```js
type Type<T> = T extends true ? "true" : "false";

declare const z: Type<boolean>;
const w: Type<true> = z; // Error, expected as z could be "false"

type BoxType<T> = {
    value: Type<T>
}

const x: BoxType<boolean> = {value: z}; // x contains x.value which is either "true" or "false"
const y: BoxType<true> = x; // x.value is "true" ?
const w2: Type<true> = y.value; // Same as w but makes Typescript happy ???
```

Comment: Nice question! I had to scour through issues a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a limitation of TypeScript.

When checking whether type `X` is assignable to type `Y`, the compiler does not always perform a full "structural check", where it fully evaluates both `X` and `Y` as much as possible and compares every member of `X` to that of `Y`, recursively... since this can be expensive.

Sometimes, if `X` and `Y` are both based on the same type... say `type X = F<A>` and `type Y = F<B>` for some `F<T>`, `A`, and `B`, then the compiler will check `A` and `B` and the *variance* of `F<T>` (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)).   If the compiler marks the definition of `F<T>` as being covariant in `T` (sort of a "read" position), contravariant in `T` (a "write" position), bivariant in `T` (both read and write), or invariant in `T` (neither read nor write),  then it will use this information to short-circuit a structural check.  If `F<T>` is covariant in `T`, for example, then if `A extends B` the compiler knows that `F<A> extends F<B>` without having to evaluate it fully.

---

This is all fine, in theory.  One problem, though, is that sometimes the compiler will assign a variance marker incorrectly, in order to make things easier and improve performance. And that is what's happening here.

Apparently conditional types of the form `type F<T> = T extends U ? X : Y` are marked as *bivariant* in `T`, meaning that unless it's doing a full structural check, the compiler will happily allow you to assign `F<A>` to `F<B>` in cases when `A extends B` (covariant) and in cases where `B extends A` (contravariant).  This is true even if the conditional type is not really bivariant (and almost nothing really is).  See the open issue [microsoft/TypeScript#27118](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27118) and specificially [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27118#issuecomment-422174853).

This is what's happening to `Type<T>`.  It has a bivariance marker on it but the type is not bivariant in `T`:

```
function foo<T, U extends T>(t: Type<T>, u: Type<U>) {
  u = t; // okay
  t = u; // okay?!
}
```

If you evaluate concrete types directly like `Type<boolean>` and `Type<true>`, they are evaluated fully and the compiler can see that `"true" | "false"` is not assignable to `"true"`.

But when you nest that inside the `BoxType<T>` type and the compiler has to compare two `BoxType<T>`s to each other, it relies on the variance marker and then will happily allow `Type<boolean>` to be assignable to `Type<true>` because `true` is assignable to `boolean`.

So this is currently just a limitation.

---

A possible workaround here is to make use of the new [optional variance annotations of type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#optional-variance-annotations-for-type-parameters) introduced in TypeScript 4.7.  One of the use cases for these markers are to help the compiler be more accurate in situations where it makes the wrong call.

It looks like `Type<T>` should really be considered covariant in `T` and definitely not contravariant.  Ideally then you'd like to mark `T` as an `out` ("read" position) parameter like this:

```
type Type<out T> = T extends true ? "true" : "false";
// error! ~~~~~ <-- Variance annotations are only supported in type aliases 
// for object, function, constructor, and mapped types
```

But I guess that's not currently supported.  Well, you can at least to it on `BoxType<T>`:

```
type BoxType<out T> = { // okay
  value: Type<T>
}
```

And now you get the behavior you wanted to see initially.

```
const x: BoxType<boolean> = { value: z };
const y: BoxType<true> = x; // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEB4YD4oF5ZQgD2BAdgCYDOUwATgK7QD8UARBdfVAFwMBmAhgDbET0A3AFgAUAHpxZeLHgIA9pWCxUGGFlwESZKrQZMBbTr35CxkrOXLzyAQigA-J06gIAtG6gA1LuQCWXPgAxtCB+PLAXMB+8vikvtCxPCBQxJRgYDZ4hFB++NKQULwB-KTmUhw2UPIARgBWEEHAADRQHJTB0bGtQbHETE02rYE5ALZcGRA5oJDEYmLtnTH5lfJIrQCqGnhEpCgAFMDscJBIyK2Ux3IbyACUUADeYlBQlOhkglAW8gDWXCDPMjvSifb5-EA0WxiAC+81EhEaPASUF6cWUAC8rqcavJ5DwIIFkCJRKj+lAAO5YxAGVRQdGgqQAUSsQw0kCaUyKpHRKMUPByNWg9G4fAEcJm0AAQvJsCdEIplCh3k9RC8AG68ahUs4wuGk5TYdjS2VyHF4gn4WkPKAanhaulQaHE-VQEBGmVyhA097YBmWazkOFAA)

Comment: Great, thank you for the answer! I knew Typescript did weird things about variance of functions, but I didn’t expect conditional types to be considered bivariant too.